# List comprehension to find unique key values in list of dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, list-comprehension

Anyone know how to perform following code using list comprehension?  I'm stuck due to the if condition, which I don't know how to apply using list comprehension.  Thanks in advance.

```
x = [{'key':1},{'key':1},{'key':2}, {'key':2}]
y = []

for e in x:
    if e['key'] not in y:
        y.append(e['key'])

>>>print y
[1,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular conditional, you can use a set comprehension:

```
xs = [{'key':1},{'key':1},{'key':2}, {'key':2}]
y = {x['key'] for x in xs}

print y # {1,2}
```

Comment: First time I've seen set comprehension.  Thanks for your help.